# ReentrantLock unlock wake up LockSupport park

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock

I have a program which have multiple threads share the same lock, just like below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockTest {
    private static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(false);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lock.lock();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-start");
                    lock.unlock();
                    LockSupport.park();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-end");
                }
                
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the "-end" should never been printed because the call to `LockSupport.park` will pause the thread. In my testing it occasionally prints the "-end" to the console, and I don't understand why.

the output looks like below:

```
Thread-7978-start
Thread-7976-end
Thread-7979-start
Thread-7980-start
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: According to the docs, a park call may return without any reason, and it is up to the caller to check the conditions for parking.

Comment: I am not aware of any condition in the JVM that is immune to spurious wake-ups. Use things like `Object.wait()`, `Condition.await()`, and `LockSupport.park()` inside a loop, and re-check the condition after awaking.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If a park can may return without any reason, I think this is a big problem because the park will not always pause my thread, this may cause some business error, how can i prevent this?

Comment: As I alluded, this is prevented by putting the call to `park()` inside a `while` loop instead of an `if` statement. Whatever condition leads you to park the thread the first time should be tested when the thread resumes; if the condition still holds, park again. This is a common idiom for pausing due to spurious wakeups.